# How to display dash as default default value in template?

Tags: angular, angular8

Using Angular 8 I have the following on my HTML:

```
<span>{{post.category || '-'}}</span>
```

If `post.category` is empty a dash will be displayed. This is working.

But I have other 2 situations a little

```
<span>{{post.createdAt || '-' | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</span>. 

<span>{{post.classification || '-'}} points</span>
```

If `createdAt` has no value the dash is not displayed ... I know it is because of the pipe.

And if `classification` has no value 'points' is still displayed ... I know it is because points is outside '-'.

How can I solve this?

Could a pipe be created for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a formatted date if it exists you could surround the `post.createdAt | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'` with parens.  Something like this.

```
<span>{{ (post?.createdAt | date:'yyyy-MM-dd') || '-' }}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest Solution is using ng-template

```
<span *ngIf="post.createdAt else dash">
  {{post.createdAt | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
</span>

<ng-template #dash>
  -
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Can't a directive or maybe pipe be created for this? I think maybe a directive to be applied to span. something like: <span defaultValue="post.createdAt;'-'"</span> ... I am looking for something more reusable.

Comment: you are already using pipe and I think for above use case, ng-template is the recommended approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show `-` sign when there is no data, then you can use ternary `?` operator:

```
<span>{{post.category ? post.category : '-'}}</span>
```

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

> The **conditional (ternary) operator** is the only JavaScript operator
>   that takes three operands: a condition followed by a question mark
>   (`?`), then an expression to execute if the condition is truthy followed
>   by a colon (`:`), and finally the expression to execute if the condition
>   is falsy. This operator is frequently used as a shortcut for the `if`
>   statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

check for the **value** if it exists pass it to `pipe` other wise display the default icon.

```
<span>{{ post?.createdAt ? (post?.createdAt | date:'yyyy-MM-dd') : '-' }}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution, i think is:

```
<span *ngIf="post?.createdAt">{{post.createdAt | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</span> 
<span *ngIf="!post?.createdAt">-</span>

<span *ngIf="post?.classification">{{post.classification}} points</span>
<span *ngIf="!post?.classification">-</span>
```